# How to access a function from a function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

When the component is function-based it's difficult to get access to the component instance.

Here's the code:

```js
const Profile = ({ userName, password, fullName }) => {
  const getFullName = (name) => {
    // ops
  }

// return ()
}
```

Is there a way to access `getFullName` in the Jest? My test is as follows:

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Test',() => {
  test('Profile' => {
    const instance = TestRenderer.create(
       <Profile userName='' password='' fullName='' />
    )
    console.log(instance.getInstance()) // undefined
  })
})
```

Comment: That function isn't accessible outside the component. That's nothing to do with Jest or React, just how JS works - it's a local variable inside a function. Test _behaviour_, not implementation; what does that function _do_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there a way to access it as we do using class component.

Comment: You shouldn't access it in a class component either, for exactly the same reason. And, again: no.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it my decision to access it or not. Do you have solution to it or not?

Comment: What part of it's **not** accessible, because that's fundamentally how the language works, is unclear? Yes it's up to you whether you want to write good code or not, but not how JS behaves.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use context or redux (toolkit) or other state management library to create a shared state between the parent and the child components.
With that you can have a shared state containing an object that is having a function as a member.
As the others commented it is a bit out of way to do. But to answer your question this is how you do would do it.

```js
// create a shared state then when you render the child
// component add the function to the shared state in that
// here is an example of function in an object
// once you added it you can use it in any component

const obj = {
  sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  },
};

// ️ using dot notation
console.log(obj.sum(10, 10)); // ️ 20

// ️ using bracket notation
console.log(obj['sum'](10, 10)); // ️ 20
```

The other way is to create an object state like this in the **parent** and send the set state as porps to the **child**. Then the child can set the state with the object containing the function it created.
Allowing the parent to use it after.

**But again:** this is not considered a proper way.